# ERROR: the accessibility modifier of the set accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer

Tags: c#

i'm having a bit of confusion with property accessors.

I'd like to have an internal property with its set accessor only accessible to derived classes.

something like this

```
internal [internalClass] MyProperty
{
get {return _prop;}
protected set {_prop = value;}
}
```

when i do this the compiler complains.

MSDN, when discussing this particular error suggests changing the `set` access modifier to `private`

which is not where i want this to go.

it looks like `Protected Internal` should be an option here however using this modifier gives the same error

I have a feeling i'm missing some basic understanding of access modifiers.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither `protected` nor `protected internal` is more restrictive than `internal`. Both would let derived types from a different assembly access the setter but not the getter. `protected internal` gives access to the *union* of `protected` and `internal`, not the *intersection*. (There is an access level representing the intersection in the CLR, but it's not exposed by C#.)

You might be best off using a private setter and a protected `SetMyProperty` method which just calls the private setter, if that matches what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Internal is more restrictive than protected.  Internal makes the member limited to the current assembly, whereas protected is accessible to an arbitrary large number of descendants outside of your assembly.

If you intend for this property to be accessible to classes or descendants outside of your assembly, you'll need to lose the internal attribute on the property.  If you intend for this property to be used only within your assembly, then make the property accessor internal.

Unfortunately, this means you have to give up protected on the accessor of internal properties.  This is an irritation because even though the property is limited to clients within your assembly, that doesn't mean you really trust all those clients to use your property correctly.  It makes sense when you are the only author running around in your assembly's source code, but I would much prefer to retain protected semantics on internal classes when there are hundreds of developers running around in the source code of one large assembly.

Comment: Taking into account tools like ILMERGE (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), and the way people use that, internal 'protection' is of even lesser value. +1 for the 'trust' on protected versus internal.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the compiler seems to believe that an internal class is permitted to have derived classes in other assemblies.  The protected field is then considered available to other assemblies, through the derived class (that is, the field has no concept on its own of its class's access modifier).  The compiler error is to indicate that (even though you know it won't ever happen) the indicated field is overextending its access rights.

Comment: This is not quite true. A public class defined in the assembly can derive from the internal class. The public class can then be derived from in another assembly. This would then make the setter accesible outside the assembly.